# Passing data between two asynctasks

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am writing an android app that allows for the user to update some info to google drive with the google sheets API.

I have one activity that updates one spreadsheet, and another activity that updates a different spreadsheet.

I have an asynctask in each activity that is responsible for executing the updating code.

**My issue is:**
I start the first activity - the user starts asynctask over there and **simultaneously** I also start the second activity, and over there the user starts the second asynctask - **meaning I can't be sure which asynctask will finish first**.

I want to report an error if one or two of the AsyncTasks fail.

My question is - **How can I interact between two PostExecute Methods in different activities?**

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of action do you want to take? What happends if the first asyncTask finishes with the activity killed?

Comment: *How can I interact between two PostExecute Methods in different activities?* as method names said it "post" a message to UI thread ... there can be only one active Activity ... so ... answer yourself

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is using `SharedPreferences` to store and retrieve data in both AsyncTasks. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/2185634) will guide you through SharedPreferences.

Another way would be to create a new `BroadcastReceiver` and notify it from the `AsyncTasks`. [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)'s a good tutorial by vogella for creating receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Start 2 `IntentServices` instead from your main activity. Make each service to report to the main activity when the service finishes its task.